# Cual es el comando que necesito utilizar

Tags: linux, centos

Uso virtualbox centos v6 y necesito hacer esta tarea, ya instalé apache pero no encuentro que comando usar para lo siguiente, los directorios ya los creé
2.  dentro de cada directorio se deberá crear (al menos) los siguientes archivos:

a)  Una página index.html que contenga (al menos):
-   El nombre del directorio donde se encuentra.
-   Un link a la pagina1.html,.
-   El nombre de cada integrante del grupo.
-   La fecha de hoy.

b)  Una página pagina1.html que contenga (al menos):
-   Un link de regreso a la página index.html de su directorio.
-   Un link a cada directorio creado.

Comment: **Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.** Para mas información puedes revisar [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

En el momento de configurar Apache con Linux, deberás asignar una carpeta donde se almacenan las paginas (var/www/html/), luego hay deberás crear los archivos html.